# angularjs form.$valid always true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I have a form and I want to check its validation, but `form.$valid` return me always true, also when form is not compiled!

```
<form name="compileForm" novalidate>
  <table class="mytable">
    <td ng-switch="question.type" style="width:25%" >
      <div directive-one ng-switch-when="text" >
      </div>

      <div  directive-two ng-switch-when="single" >
        <div class="radio" ng-repeat="(optionIndex, option) in my.choices">
          <input type="radio" 
                 name="optradio{{groupIndex}}_{{qIndex}}"
             id="optradio{{groupIndex}}_{{qIndex}}_{{optionIndex}}"
                 ng-model="option.select" 
                 ng-value="true" 
                 ng-change="changeValue(my.choices, optionIndex, qIndex, groupIndex)" 
                 ng-disabled="{{sdisable}}"  
                 required>
          <label class="radio-inline" 
                 for="optradio{{groupIndex}}_{{qIndex}}_{{optionIndex}}">{{option.option}}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </td>
    <td> <span>{{compileForm.$valid}}</span></td>
  </table>  
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: You should build a JSFiddle with a sample data, it's hard to find the problem, it's possible you have a radio selected by default, so the form is valid.

Comment: I tryed to build a jsfiddle (is the first time i make it) but it doesn't work....
anyway, the jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/0ntpdved/2/